# Rest of the query doesn't see modifications made inside WITH?

Tags: postgresql, common-table-expression

I have a hierarchy of things:

```
CREATE TABLE thing (
  id serial NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT thing_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)

CREATE TABLE thingthing (
  part integer NOT NULL,
  cont integer NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT thingthing_part_fkey FOREIGN KEY (part) REFERENCES thing (id),
  CONSTRAINT thingthing_cont_fkey FOREIGN KEY (cont) REFERENCES thing (id)
)
```

I wrote a query that disconnects a thing from another and should also remove it if it is no more connected to any other.

```
WITH cte AS (
  DELETE FROM thingthing
  WHERE part = $1 AND cont = $2
)
DELETE FROM thing
WHERE id = $1 AND id NOT IN (SELECT part FROM thingthing)
```

The problem is that the second `DELETE` never runs and I end up having things in the `thing` table which are not connected to others.

My question is why it doesn't run when the first `DELETE` already removed the last record from `thingthing` where `part` had `$1` as value. In this case I'd expect `id NOT IN (SELECT part FROM thingthing)` to be true, but it's not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Quote from the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING)

> All the statements are executed with the same snapshot (see [Chapter 13](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/mvcc.html)), so they cannot “see” one another's effects on the target tables. [...] and means that RETURNING data is the only way to communicate changes between different WITH sub-statements and the main query.